# Add plugin to vu Instance as "Vue.use()" without the root vue js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, instance, directus

I'm working on a Directus Project. 
Directus is a Headless CMS made in PHP and Vue.js.

I would like to use a theme or a plugin like Vuetify on a custom page. 
A plugin is often called like this:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'; // Something like that

Vue.use(...)
```

But i don't have access to the file where Vue is instantiated.

Do you know if i can add plugins and themes from children files project ? How ?

I thank you by advance for your future responses!!

Cordially,

Nicolas

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can add plugins after the Vue instance was create.

See the bellow example:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button type="button" @click="installPlugin">install plugin</button>
    <button type="button" @click="callPlugin">call plugin</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  methods: {
    installPlugin() {
      this.$root.constructor.use({
        install(Vue, options) {
          console.log('plugin was installed');
          Vue.prototype.$test = () => console.log('plugin was called');
        },
      });
    },
    callPlugin() {
      this.$test();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

In this example, the plugin was installed and called in a child component.

Comment: I think my explanation is wrong, i can't access to the file where there is `import Vue from 'vue'` . My file is a child file which is dumb and it can access to some property given by the CMS like "this.$api". I tried to install many plugin like vuetify, vue-dummy, popper.js. But nothing is happenning when, in a child file, i set `javascript import Vue from 'vue'`, `import VueDummy from "vue-dummy"`, `Vue.use(VueDummy)` and i call the new component in a template.

Comment: I see. You can install plugin using `this.$root.constructor.use()`. I changed my answer with complete example.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people.